# Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in \www\test.php on line 7

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use include within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619573/how-to-use-include-within-a-function)

i have two file

**inc.php file**

```
<?php
$var1 = "foo";
$var1 .= "bar";
?>
```

**test.php File**

```
<?php
function getcontent($file) {
 include ($file);
}

getcontent('inc.php');
echo $var1;
?>
```

When i run test.php it give me error in output

```
Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in \www\test.php on line 7
```

But when i change my test.php file to this

```
<?php
include ('inc.php');
echo $var1;
?>
```

its works, and give me output fine

```
foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it by this

```
function getcontent($file) {
    include ($file);
}
getcontent('inc.php');
```

it includes as

```
function getcontent($file) {
    $var1 = "foo";
    $var1 .= "bar";
}
```

actually your variables are being included inside the function and not visible outside of the function so the error message occurs.

[**See this SO answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619573/how-to-use-include-within-a-function)

Comment: so this will not work i include in inc.php???

Comment: Not outside the function if it's not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare $var1 as global var.

```
global $var1;

$var1 = "foo";
$var1 .= "bar";
```

**OR**

```
$GLOBALS['var1'] = "foo";
$GLOBALS['var1'] .= "bar";
```

Comment: He doesn't have $var2 ;-). I'm sure you have ment $var1 only.

Comment: @Stan, Thanks to observe, i've done an update =)

Answer (score 0):

when you include the file in the `getcontent` function, the vars behave like they were defined there and aren't visible to the outside.

if you declared them as `global`, it would work.