# PHP code does not behave the same if called via function

Tags: php

The same code used as below works fine, but when you un-comment the function and try to call the function, it does not behave the same?
Am trying to standardize the CRUD using functions, but running into issues.

1. The print_r does not display the output when called inside a function but works when called as is outside of a function
2. the return value does not return when called via a function
3. I would like to get the return values via the function and decide what to do next.

Appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks

```
<?php
    //function verifyemail($p_email) {
        echo "insde function - " . $p_email;
        try {
            //      $p_email = "r@gmail.com";
            include 'db.php';
            connectDB('msme_db',1) ;
            $sql = "select count(*) as p_exists from    msme_users where user_email = '$p_email' ;" ;
            echo $sql ;
            $result = $__conn->prepare($sql);
            $result->execute();
            $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $row = $result->fetch() ;
            //print_r ($row);
            if ($row)
            {
                $i = $row['p_exists'] ;
                return $row !== false ? $row : 'x';
            } 
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo  " in catch" ;
            die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
       }
//} // End of Function

//$email = "r@gmail.com";
//echo sprintf('Email %s is %s', $mail, verifyemail($email)) ;
print_r($row) ;
?>
```

Comment: `$__conn` might be undefined when inside a function (because of scope). Is it defined in `db.php`? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619578/4830296

Comment: And if `fetch()` fails the function doesn't return anything

Comment: do a `var_dump($__conn);` before you use it to see if it's defined.

Comment: also the return value will be an array ($row), so you'll get the `NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number x` for `sprintf('Email %s is %s', $mail, verifyemail($email))`

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:
1. you have `return` command in `if` statement

```
if ($row)
{
    $i = $row['p_exists'] ;
    return $row !== false ? $row : 'x';
}
```

so `if` is `true` then you `return` from function and `if` is not true then you don't
check this by putting `echo` inside and see if you see anything

```
if ($row)
{
    echo 'IF Statemen in line: ' . __LINE__ . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
    $i = $row['p_exists'] ;
    return $row !== false ? $row : 'x';
}
```

you should rewrite the code so you always return form the function and use `if` statement only to assign value to `$i` or `$row`
ie like that:

```
function verifyemail($p_email) {
    echo "insde function - " . $p_email;
    try {
        //      $p_email = "r@gmail.com";
        include 'db.php';
        connectDB('msme_db',1) ;
        $sql = "select count(*) as p_exists from    msme_users where user_email = '$p_email' ;" ;
        echo $sql ;
        $result = $__conn->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $row = $result->fetch() ;
        //print_r ($row);
        if ($row)
        {
            $i = $row['p_exists'] ; //<== where do you use $i?
            $row !== false ? $row : 'x';
        } 
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo  " in catch" ;
        die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
   }
   return $row; //<== here you rentrun from the function
} 
// End of Function
// ^ here is place for the comment, not in the line where } is

//$email = "r@gmail.com";
//echo sprintf('Email %s is %s', $mail, verifyemail($email)) ;
print_r($row) ;
?>
```

2. If you use return statement without the function body so in the global code scope you end the php script execution
   so the code

   ```
   print_r($row) ;
   ```

is never executed

to summarize - put echo statements

```
echo 'line: ' . __LINE__ . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

into if statement and other places and check numbers with the code and you'll probably see what you havn't seen where your execution flows where not.
and move return statement outside `if` statement, perfectly at the end of the function.

Comment: this `return $row;` could result in an uncatched error '$row is undefined'

Comment: you're right this `return $row;` assumes there is always a value of `$row` so `$row` should have been assigned with default value before or `return $row;` be in if statement at the end where you return value of `$row` or default value ie `false`